Use of animation on mobile intro screens
I am working on a mobile app for a client and have used static placeholder images in the first three intro screens, the usual UX pattern from my point of view.
The client has hired an animator who has suggested using an animation (not just transition animation) on the first of the intro screens. This animation uses a few different illustrations in one loop which then resolves and doesn't loop round.
I feel that this is incorrect from a UX perspective as it could be distracting and I don't think I have seen this pattern used before.
Any thoughts? Does any other app do this? Thank you in advance!

I have seen this many times, so I guess the problem comes down to user testing as usual
